# searching in large tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have some items from a table and I want to search for each item's id in other 4 tables (that currently have around 5k-6k rows but will be larger in the future).

```
$items = ItemStock::all();

        foreach($items as $item) {
            $checklist = ChecklistItem::find($item->id);
            if($checklist == null) {
                $r_checklist = ReturningChecklistItem::find($item->id);
                if($r_checklist == null) {
                    $transfer = TransferItem::find($item->id);    
                    if($transfer == null) {
                        $consumption = ConsumptionItem::find($item->id);     
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
```

I have to search through all tables (as above) and if I don't find the item in one of the tables, I keep searching in the others. But this will not be efficient if the tables will be larger in the future.

Is there a way that can be more efficient? Also, these items will be shown in one of the pages, so I should include a loading spinner until the all the items will load (after checking in the code above). Is this a good approach?

Comment: why isn't there some identifier to say what table the record exists in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest read [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)

Then for query optimization [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

And the other form is use Inner or Left Joins For the related data to Item